# Mongoid: How to sync both sides of a HABTM relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I have two models:

```
class User
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  ...
end

class Group
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  ...
end
```

For some reason the group object doesn't have all the `user_ids`. Maybe, because I'm using mongoid 4 alpha version.

```
Group _id: 123, user_ids: [1, 2, 4]
User _id: 3, group_ids: [123, 456]
```

Although the big issue is why are those documents unsync, for now I need to know how to sync them at this point.

Thanks in advance,

Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why the documents where unsync. I was setting the group in a NEW user object (not persisted):

```
group = Group.last
user = User.new
user.groups = [group]
user.save
```

According to [mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many), it stores the group_ids in the `user` but not in the `group`:

> Model#{name}= Set the related documents. **If the parent document is
>   persisted, then the child will be saved immediately along with the
>   parent to keep the keys consistent.** If setting to nil or [] then the
>   children will be deleted.

To fix the issue I saved the group after the user is saved: `group.save`

Given that I only had one group and that the users are persisted now, I did the following rake task to sync the data:

```
users = User.in(group_ids: group.id)

users.each do |user|
  g = user.groups.first
  user.groups = [g]
  user.save
end
```